# Select statements 10x slower in mySQL 8 compared to mySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have the same application running in two instances on my Windows PC. Both instances are identical, except one uses MySQL 5.7.28 and the other uses MySQL 8.0.16.

Select queries take roughly 10 times longer on MySQL 8. I also see this same slower performance on the live environment, which is a Linux server.

The slowdown occurs for all tables in the database, but I will give one concrete example below:

The query `select * from available_times` takes 0.007s on MySQL 5.7 and 0.065s on MySQL 8

This is the create statement for available_times table:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

CREATE TABLE `available_times` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `monday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `tuesday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `tuesday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `wednesday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `wednesday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `thursday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `thursday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `friday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `friday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `saturday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `saturday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `sunday_start` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `sunday_end` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There are 6927 rows in the table, but all contain similar information. Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO `available_times` (`id`, `week_no`, `year`, `monday_start`, `monday_end`, `tuesday_start`, `tuesday_end`, `wednesday_start`, `wednesday_end`, `thursday_start`, `thursday_end`, `friday_start`, `friday_end`, `saturday_start`, `saturday_end`, `sunday_start`, `sunday_end`) VALUES
(1, 44, 2011,   '9:00', '17:30',    '9:00', '17:30',    '9:00', '17:30',    '9:00', '17:30',    '9:00', '17:30',    '9:00', '18:00',    'None', 'None'),
(1, 45, 2011,   '9:00', '19:00',    '9:00', '19:00',    '9:00', '19:00',    '9:00', '19:00',    '9:00', '19:00',    '9:00', '19:00',    'None', 'None'),
(60,    44, 2011,   'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', '8:30', '18:30',    '10:15',    '20:00',    '8:30', '20:30',    '8:30', '13:00',    'None', 'None'),
(60,    45, 2011,   '10:15',    '20:00',    '8:30', '18:15',    '10:15',    '20:30',    '8:30', '20:30',    '10:00',    '17:00',    '7:15', '14:30',    '10:00',    '12:00'),
(60,    46, 2023,   '11:00',    '17:30',    '11:00',    '17:30',    '11:00',    '17:30',    '11:00',    '17:30',    '11:00',    '17:30',    'None', 'None', 'None', 'None');
```

This is the MySQL 5.7 cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
{{#unless os.windows}}
skip-name-resolve
{{/unless}}

datadir = {{datadir}}
port = {{port}}
bind-address = {{bindAddress}}
socket = {{socket}}

{{#if os.windows}}
console
{{/if}}

# Fine Tuning
performance_schema = off
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8

# InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
innodb_log_file_size = 96M

[client]
{{#unless os.windows}}
socket = {{socket}}
{{else}}
host = {{clientAddress}}
port = {{port}}
{{/unless}}
user = root
password = root
```

and this is the cnf for MySQL 8:

```
[mysqld]
{{#unless os.windows}}
skip-name-resolve
{{/unless}}

{{#if disableMysqlx}}
mysqlx = 0
{{/if}}

datadir = {{datadir}}
port = {{port}}
bind-address = {{bindAddress}}
socket = {{socket}}

{{#if os.windows}}
console
{{/if}}

# Older PHP/client compatibility
character-set-server = utf8mb3
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password

# Fine Tuning
performance_schema = off
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8

# InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
innodb_log_file_size = 96M

[client]
{{#unless os.windows}}
socket = {{socket}}
{{else}}
host = {{clientAddress}}
port = {{port}}
{{/unless}}
user = root
password = root
```

The `explain select * from available_times` is the same for both:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,available_times,,ALL,,,,,6927,"100.00",
```

Any help diagnosing this issue would be very gratefully received!

MySQL 8: explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE student_id = 6001 AND ((status = 1 AND date_stamp < 1698233040) OR status = 2) ORDER BY date_stamp

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "10807.28"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "1188.85"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "lessons",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 91452,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 1188,
        "filtered": "1.30",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "9499.54",
          "eval_cost": "118.88",
          "prefix_cost": "9618.43",
          "data_read_per_join": "222K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "student_id",
          "instructor_id",
          "start_time",
          "duration",
          "type",
          "day",
          "month",
          "year",
          "notes",
          "date_stamp",
          "approved",
          "status",
          "payment_status",
          "payment_type",
          "last_minute",
          "price",
          "created_date"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`local`.`lessons`.`student_id` = 6001) and (((`local`.`lessons`.`status` = 1) and (`local`.`lessons`.`date_stamp` < 1698233040)) or (`local`.`lessons`.`status` = 2)))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

MySQL 5.7: explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE student_id = 6001 AND ((status = 1 AND date_stamp < 1698233040) OR status = 2) ORDER BY date_stamp

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "21372.16"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "1188.85"
      },
      "table": {
        "table_name": "lessons",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 91452,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 1188,
        "filtered": "1.30",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "19945.54",
          "eval_cost": "237.77",
          "prefix_cost": "20183.31",
          "data_read_per_join": "222K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "student_id",
          "instructor_id",
          "start_time",
          "duration",
          "type",
          "day",
          "month",
          "year",
          "notes",
          "date_stamp",
          "approved",
          "status",
          "payment_status",
          "payment_type",
          "last_minute",
          "price",
          "created_date"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`local`.`lessons`.`student_id` = 6001) and (((`local`.`lessons`.`status` = 1) and (`local`.`lessons`.`date_stamp` < 1698233040)) or (`local`.`lessons`.`status` = 2)))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show query plans for both server

Comment: I have edited the question and added that at the end

Comment: I think, this is too simple query. Difference 0.007s  vs 0.065s my have many reasons. In particular, in the method of measuring query execution time. Need to look at a heavier query.

Comment: I chose this query as an example because it is simple but still illustrates the time difference. I can add another example to the question if it will help? This query takes 0.62s in MySQL 8 and 0.024s in 5.7: 

SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE student_id = 6001 AND ((status = 1 AND date_stamp < 1698233040) OR status = 2) ORDER BY date_stamp

Comment: Yes, this query is more interesting. What is rowcount and size of table ``lessons``? And ``explain FORMAT=JSON``?

Comment: Lessons is 91,452 rows. phpMyAdmin shows space usage as 8.3 MiB.

Comment: I added the results of the explain to the bottom of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255734/discussion-between-alex-rees-and-valnik).

Comment: Is a SINGLE PC used for both versions? Yes or No ?
Additional DB information request from EACH MySQL version, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post 2 TEXT data sets on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Yes, a single PC is used for both versions. Intel i5-6600K 4 Cores, 8GB RAM, SSD Drive.

I'm using Adminer to run these sql commands and STATUS; results in an error.

My UPTIME is currently about 5 hours but I can check again after 24 hours if necessary.

5.7: https://justpaste.it/3cujg
8.0: https://justpaste.it/c1ikl

Comment: It's not serious, but I'll ask: Is SSD drive Samsung XXX PRO nvme or similar?

Comment: SSD drive is Samsung 850 Evo. We get the same slowdown with the live site which runs on a Linux server, so I don't think it is a problem with my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is a performance killer.  It lead to `ALL` in the Explains.  `UNION` *usually* is a good workaround:

```
    (   SELECT  *
            FROM  lessons
            WHERE  student_id = 6001
              AND  status = 1
              AND  date_stamp < 1698233040
            ORDER BY  date_stamp
            
    )
    UNION ALL
    (   SELECT  *
            FROM  lessons
            WHERE  student_id = 6001
              AND  status = 2
            ORDER BY  date_stamp 
    )
    ORDER BY  date_stamp   -- yes, repeat this
```

And have

```
INDEX(student_id, status, data_stamp)  -- in this order
```

Also, switch to `ENGINE=InnoDB` -- MyISAM will be removed; meanwhile, no work is being done on it by the developers.

It is probably inefficient to split the date into its components in columns.  Toss the columns, then use datetime functions to split the date apart.  Also, use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, no integers.

Comment: Yep .. Innodb is WAY better .. and you must search by an Index if you want fast results, so that it only has to look at the requested results and  not everything that exists to compare.